# How to Get All the Options of "Image Size" in Photoshop for an Object/Layer

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

Ok so what would seem to be the simplest thing to do is harder than ever to figure out and look up online cause there seems to be no answer.

All i want to do is shrink the size of an object/layer anyway that i want. I have always been confused how there wasn't an option in "Image Size..." to adjust just the object and not entire document. Cause what i want to do is shrink the object by a certain percentage % like you can in the image size option but for some reason it seems the only option is "free transform" which doesn't have all these options like changing by %. So can someone please explain if this is possible.If not the only thing i can do is make two documents and change the image size in one then copy that image over to the other document with the same canvas size. And this is stupid and time consuming

Answer (score 0):

Yooo! Ok, so first, select the object you would like to transform by holding down the `Ctrl` button and clicking on the objects Layer Thumbnail.

Now that your object is selected, press `Ctrl+T`, this brings the object into free transform mode.

Now if you look at the top bar, you will see that there are 'W:100%' and 'H:100%' options, change these to scale the Width and Height of your your object.

[image]

Hope this was helpful! <3